# Global config object

Tags: c#

I want to initialize kind of global object, which I can refer anytime and from any part of my application. I don't want to pass it from one method to another down the execution process, I just want to read all information once from my config file and store it into object and when use that information any time I need from any place. 
My problem is that not sure about how to declare that class technically to be accessible and won't cleaned by garbage collector. Could you please provide a code example of such "Global class".

Looking for your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a singleton to declare it. [Here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) are some sample implementations. I personally prefer to use a static class with properties

```
public static class Config
{
    public static string IP { get {...
```

Remember, as long as anything has a reference to your instance, it won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Bill Gates should really know these things